# How to apply math operations to each number from a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner at python (one week). Here I am trying print the list of all the prime factor of 60. But for line 19, I am getting following error:
*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'float' and 'list'*

The code:

```
whylist = []
factor = []
boom = []
primefactor = []
n = 60
j = (list(range(1, n, 1)))



for numbers in j:
    if n%numbers == 0:
        whylist.append(numbers)
        for everynumber in whylist:
            factor.append(everynumber)

for things in factor:
    u = (list(range(1, things, 1)))
    d = float(things)
    if d%u == 0:
        boom.append(things)
    if len(boom) == 1:
        for every in boom:
            primefactor.append(every)
print(primefactor)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Levon `range` doesn't return a list on python3.x, but you're right, I don't think `list(range(...))` is necessary here.

Comment: @mgilson Ah .. yes, good point .. didn't notice the tag .. thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To apply a math operation to every element in a list you can use a list-comprehension:

```
new_list = [ x%num for x in old_list]
```

There are other ways to do it as well.  Sometimes people will use `map`

```
new_list = map(lambda x: x%num, old_list)
```

but most people prefer the first form which is generally more efficient and clear than using `lambda` (which can be a little confusing when you're just starting to learn python).

**EDIT**

Here's a recursive implementation of what you were trying:

```
def factorize(n):
    out=[]
    for i in range(2,n):
        if(n%i == 0): #first thing to hit this is always prime
            out.append(i) #add it to the list
            out+=factorize(n/i)  #get the list of primes from the other factor and append to this list.
            return out
        else:
            return [n] # n%i was never 0, must be prime.

print factorize(2000)
```

Comment: Looks like my planning was wrong, fixing u as list now gives me ouput [2,2] (I am looking for prime factor) can I get a clue on what I might be assuming wrong?

Comment: @MubtasimSh -- I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your code and what you're trying to do with it.  I've added a recursive factorize function which seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use numpy arrays instead of lists.

```
import numpy as np
j = np.arange(1,n,1)
rem = np.mod(j,num)
```

and numpy will take care of broadcasting operations for you.  It should also be faster than list comprehensions or map.

Comment: The vector ops are handy, but one easy-to-overlook danger when using numpy for Euler problems is that unless you use `dtype=object` or something the integers won't be arbitrary-precision.

Comment: @tcaswell -- Numpy is great.  I toyed with the idea of adding it to my answer, but I decided that my answer would be more "pure" without it.  I'm glad you added it though.  Here, you could just use the `%` operator and it would still work.  `rem = j%num`

Comment: @DSM True, but that should only become an issue when dealing with large numbers at which point brute forcing the problem is probably not the right solution.

Comment: @mgilson I have a tendency to be as explicit as possible.  An advantage of `np.mod` over `%` is than you can throw an iterable at it  and it will still do 'the right thing', where as `%` will complain.